# Pyspark accessing and exploding nested items of a json

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I'm very new to spark and i'm trying to parse a json file containing data to be aggregated but i can't manage to navigate its content.
I searched for for other solutions but i wasn't able to find anything that worked in my case.

This is the schema of the dataframe of imported json:

```
root
  |-- UrbanDataset: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |-- context: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- coordinates: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- format: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- height: long (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- language: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- producer: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- schemeID: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- timeZone: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- specification: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- id: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- schemeID: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- propertyDefinition: array (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- codeList: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- dataType: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- propertyDescription: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- propertyName: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- subProperties: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- propertyName: array (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- unitOfMeasure: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- values: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- line: array (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- coordinates: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- format: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- height: double (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- period: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- end_ts: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- start_ts: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- property: array (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- val: string (nullable = true)
```

A subset of the whole json is attached [here](https://pastebin.com/zZXhRTXj)

My goal is to retrieve the **values** struct from this schema and manipulating/aggregating all the **val** located in line.element.property.element.val

I tried also to explode it to get every field in a column "csv style" but i got the error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'array(`UrbanDataset`.`context`, `UrbanDataset`.`specification`, `UrbanDataset`.`values`)'  due to data type mismatch: input to function array should all be the same type

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

df = spark.read.format('json').load('data1.json')
df.select(psf.explode(psf.array("UrbanDataset.*"))).show()
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a small excerpt of the dataset?

Comment: sure, just added a subset of the total lines (they should be 96, one every 15 minutes).

Comment: Well, I have not worked with loading `json` before. If I could see the picture of the DataFrame, then I could help you in exploding it. I could not load this `json` file. May be I am not doing it correctly, that's why I am asking for a view of the dataframe.

Comment: idk, the json has been validated. However how can i show you the picture of the DataFrame? It's not the posted schema? What do you mean exactly? Tnx

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access directly nested arrays, you need to use `explode` before. 
It will create a line for each element in the array.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("Value", F.explode("Values"))
```

Comment: so, in this specific situation, how can i access the field lines containing the array to explode? ty