# How do you parse an array of JSON objects into a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: json, apache-spark, twitter, pyspark, databricks

I have a collection of JSON files containing Twitter data that I'd like to use as a datasource for structured streaming in Databricks/Spark. The JSON files have the following structure:

```
[{...tweet data...},{...tweet data...},{...tweet data...},...]
```

My PySpark code:

```
# Stream from the /tmp/tweets folder
tweetstore = "/tmp/tweets/"

# Set up the folder as a streaming source
streamingInputDF = (
  spark \
    .readStream \
    .schema(json_schema) \
    .json(tweetstore)
)

# Check
streamingInputDF.isStreaming

# Access the DF using SQL
streamingQuery = streamingInputDF \
  .select("run_stamp", "user", "id", "source", "favorite_count", "retweet_count")\
  .writeStream \
  .format("memory") \
  .queryName("tweetstream") \
  .outputMode("append")\
  .start()

streamingDF = spark.sql("select * from tweetstream order by 1 desc")
```

My output looks like this:

```
Number of entries in dataframe: 3875046
+---------+----+----+------+--------------+-------------+
|run_stamp|user|id  |source|favorite_count|retweet_count|
+---------+----+----+------+--------------+-------------+
|null     |null|null|null  |null          |null         |
|null     |null|null|null  |null          |null         |
|null     |null|null|null  |null          |null         |
```

From what I can tell, I probably need to use `UDF` or `explode()` to parse the JSON array properly but haven't quite figured out how so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811652/pyspark-accessing-and-exploding-nested-items-of-a-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documenting the answer for others who might stumble upon this: I realised the JSON didn't have one object per line as Spark expects. The key then, was to add `.option("multiline", True)`, i.e.:

```
streamingInputDF = (
  spark \
    .readStream \
    .option("multiline", True) \
    .schema(json_schema) \
    .json(tweetstore)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working well for me on sample data-

```scala
 val data = """[{"id":1,"name":"abc1"},{"id":2,"name":"abc2"},{"id":3,"name":"abc3"}]"""
    val df = spark.read.json(Seq(data).toDS())
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+----+
      * |id |name|
      * +---+----+
      * |1  |abc1|
      * |2  |abc2|
      * |3  |abc3|
      * +---+----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: long (nullable = true)
      * |-- name: string (nullable = true)
      */
```